# AdventureWorks activation error in SQL Server, I don't know if it is my pathway is wrong or my database is wrong

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlcmd, adventureworks

I'm trying to add AdventureWorks to my SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. After I opened the query in SQLCMD code, I changed the `setvar` path to my server name.

How do I fix this error?

I have the following error message:

```
Started - 2016-07-09 00:32:33.533

*** Dropping Database

*** Creating Database
```

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 89
>   Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.DACHENMCIS\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorksDW2014_Data.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 89
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

```
*** Checking for AdventureWorksDW2014 Database
*** AdventureWorksDW2014 Database does not exist. Make sure that the script is being run in SQLCMD mode and that the variables have been correctly set.
```

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 119
>   Database 'AdventureWorksDW2014' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vDMPrep, Line 1683
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.FactInternetSales'.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vTimeSeries, Line 1731
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.vDMPrep'.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vTargetMail, Line 1796
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.DimCustomer'.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vAssocSeqOrders, Line 1828
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.vDMPrep'.

Comment: The relevant error is "The system cannot find the path specified."  Does `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.DACHENMCIS\MSSQL\DATA\ ` exist?

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. DACHENMCIS is my sql server name, the instruction for my lab says that. But I can't seem to fix it? do I need more to my sql server name?

Comment: Also if you can, can I email you? too long to type here.

Comment: As already mentioned, did you check to see that `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.DACHENMCIS\MSSQL\DATA\` exists?

Comment: Well for the lab, it says replace the MSSQL with my servername, and my server name is Dachenmcis/ssqlerserver. Do I have to create a path? If so can you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add privileges to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.DACHENMCIS\MSSQL\DATA\", you don't have all required.

Or if possibly the path is not valid, Replace "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.DACHENMCIS\MSSQL\DATA\" with an existing folder path on which you have full privileges and you'll be fine.

Comment: Can you please show me the code instruction on how to create a path? on my lab it says before i start, I need to replace the default path with my server name.

Comment: The instruction says in SQLCMD mode, I need to replace this line. :setvar SqlSamplesDatabasePath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"

Comment: I'm supose to copy and paste my own server name in the.mssqlserver part? But I keep doing it wrong? Can you show me how to do it. I promise I will accept your answer!

Comment: It's most likely the privileges on the folder.  Can you ckeck it?  Or somebody do it for the user you're using.